# Phonon VLC backend settings

Tags: vlc

I am testing video hardware acceleration and I would like to know, where are settings of VLC-backend for phonon. Are changes made in VLC itself actual changes that are applied to the backend itself (which in turn should be system wide, not just for vlc)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that versed in Phonon etc. but from the looks of it VLC can either use Gstreamer or itself. I'm concluding this based on this forum post, titled: [phonon-backend-gstreamer vs phonon-backend-vlc vs phonon-bac](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=102437).

*excerpt*

> phonon-backend-gstreamer vs phonon-backend-vlc vs phonon-backend-xine
>
> What are the advantages and disadvantages of phonon-backend-gstreamer,
>   phonon-backend-vlc, and phonon-backend-xine. I was reading this and
>   got curious.

There was a link within that thread to this page: https://community.kde.org/Phonon/FeatureMatrix which included the following matrix which might help you in deciding which to use.

[image: ss1]